# Advertencia al compilar formulario en Java

Tags: java

## Hola, muy buenas noches

Hoy les traigo un problema para ver si me podían ayudar con esta advertencia que me da [jcreator](/questions/tagged/jcreator) Pro al compilar mi programa de Java

> Note: C:\Users\JosePadron\Documents\JCreator Pro\MyProjects\SistemaFacturacion\formularios\frmLogin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
>
> Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

```
Process completed.
```

Codigo de frmLogin.java

```
package formularios;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;

public class frmLogin extends JFrame {
//Componentes
private JLabel lblUsuario;
private JLabel lblClave;
private JLabel lblImagen;
private JTextField txtUsuario;
private JPasswordField txtClave;
private JButton btnAceptar;
private JButton btnCancelar;


public frmLogin() {
    //Colocamos propiedades del formulario
    setTitle("Ingreso al sistema");
    setLayout(null);
    setSize(390, 180);
    setResizable(false);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    
    //Creacion de iconos
    Icon icoAceptar = new 
  ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images/aceptar.jpg"));
    Icon icoCancelar = new 
 ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images/cancelar.png"));
    Icon icoImagen = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images/ingreso.png"));
    
    //Creacion de objetos
    lblUsuario = new JLabel("Usuario:");
    txtUsuario = new JTextField(10);
    lblClave = new JLabel("Clave:");
    txtClave = new JPasswordField(10);
    lblImagen = new JLabel(icoImagen);
    btnAceptar = new JButton("Aceptar", icoAceptar);
    btnCancelar = new JButton("Cancelar", icoCancelar);
    
    
    //Adicionar objetos al formulario
    add(lblUsuario);
    add(txtUsuario);
    add(lblClave);
    add(txtClave);
    add(btnAceptar);
    add(btnCancelar);
    add(lblImagen);
    
    //Propiedades de los objetos
    btnAceptar.setHorizontalTextPosition(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    btnAceptar.setVerticalTextPosition(SwingConstants.BOTTOM);
    btnAceptar.setToolTipText("Ingresa al sistema");
    
    btnCancelar.setHorizontalTextPosition(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    btnCancelar.setVerticalTextPosition(SwingConstants.BOTTOM);
    btnCancelar.setToolTipText("Cancela la operacion de ingresar al sistema");
    
    //Colocar los objetos en el formulario
    lblUsuario.reshape(20, 20, 100, 20);
    txtUsuario.reshape(120, 20, 100, 20);
    lblImagen.reshape(240, 20, 128, 128);
    
    lblClave.reshape(20, 45, 100, 20);
    txtClave.reshape(120, 45, 100, 20);
    
    btnAceptar.reshape(20, 75, 90, 60);
    btnCancelar.reshape(120, 75, 90, 60);
            
    
    
}
}
```

Comment: por lo que veo en tu problema la compilación sí se ejecuta correctamente, el problema es que usas un método que es obsoleto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El culpable es el metodo `reshape()`, esta desaconsejado usarlo, en vez de ese puedes usar el método `setBounds()` que de igual manera recibe 4 argumentos.